# Excel - INDEX MATCH WITH DIFFERENT CONDITION

Tags: microsoft-excel

[IF g.P= 1900[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJIbW.png)

i want 
if g.p = 1800 then 
INDEX(D2:D6,MATCH(B4,D2:D6,-1))

g.p = 1900 then 
INDEX(E2:E6,MATCH(B4,E2:E6,-1))

Comment: So what keeps you from using `IF(...)` with your condition and formula??

Answer (score 0):

Then use a second match for the column:

```
=INDEX(D2:F6,MATCH(B4,INDEX(D2:F6,0,MATCH(B2,D1:F1,0)),-1),MATCH(B2,D1:F1,0))
```

[image]